# Which is better java + OpenGl or C++ OpenGl?

Tags: animation

I do not have any experience regarding #D animation.
But which one is better java with open GL or c++?
What is the diffrence between java 3d and opengl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Which one is better" needs a metric to be possible to answer.

If performance is the metric, then the answer is C++ and OpenGL. This is (among other things) because calls between Java and native can be a little bit more time-consuming, and C++ has arrays that are more in line with what OpenGL expects.

But if the metric is something like how quickly a Java developer will be able to make something with reasonable performance, the answer will probably be Java + OpenGL.

Java3D is a higher level API than OpenGL.

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that Processing (http://processing.org/) is a quite nice Java environment for graphics programming. It includes support for OpenGL.

Comment: but can i develope the same quality graphics with java3d as like opeGl?

Comment: Pure OpenGL is more powerful, but also much more complicated and time consuming. You'll get results quicker with a higher level API, but OpenGL will ultimately be able to provide features that Java3D won't be able to.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend going for C++ with OpenGL.

My only experience with Java and 3D animation is via [JOGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_OpenGL) and I can't say that it was at all positive.  From memory, the interface made you write C-like code in Java.  It removed a lot of the benefits of using Java (easy to read code, convenience, etc) and adds nothing but burden (anything you write in Java with OpenGL is likely to be slower than the C++ counterpart).